# Getting "NO DATA' on strategy tester when changing input parameters for crossover script

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am just learning pinescript so i apologize if this seems like stupid question, this is my 1st script. I am trying to code a simple ma crossover strategy. when i use the defvals (5/20) the strategy tester populates just fine. but when i change the input parameters to 50/200 for example, it does not work. looking for some assistance. thank you

```
strategy("Cross Over Strategies", overlay=true)

//get user input
fastMaLength = input.int(title="fast ma length", defval=5, minval=1, maxval=200, tooltip="Donchian Parameter= 5/20, golden cross = 50/200")
slowMaLength = input.int(title="slow ma length", defval=20, minval=1 , maxval=200, tooltip="Donchian Parameter= 5/20, golden cross = 50/200")

//calcs
//get ma values
maFast = ta.sma(close, fastMaLength)
maSlow = ta.sma(close, slowMaLength)

//calc crossover
bullCross = ta.crossover(maFast, maSlow)
bearCross = ta.crossunder(maFast, maSlow)

//detect buy and sell filter
//detect buy and sell filters--strategy.position_size == 0 so we only enter when not in trade
buySignal = bullCross and not na(maFast) and not na(maSlow) and strategy.position_size == 0 and barstate.isconfirmed
sellSignal = bearCross and not na(maFast) and not na(maSlow) and strategy.position_size == 0 and barstate.isconfirmed

//enter buy orders
if buySignal
    strategy.entry(id="long", direction=strategy.long)

//enter sell orders
if sellSignal
    strategy.entry(id="short", direction=strategy.short)
    
// strategy.close function used for exiting on bool conditions
//close longs
if strategy.position_size > 0 and bearCross
    strategy.close(id="long")
//close shorts
if strategy.position_size > 0 and bullCross
    strategy.close(id="short")
    
//draw data to chart
plot(maFast, color=color.green, linewidth=2)
plot(maSlow, color=color.red, linewidth=2)
plotshape(bullCross, color=color.green, style=shape.triangleup, location=location.belowbar, size=size.normal)
plotshape(bearCross, color=color.red, style=shape.triangledown, location=location.abovebar, size=size.normal)
```

Comment: update: solved this was in fact a stupid question. buy/sell signals were set to only enter if strategy.position_size == 0 when this strategy should be in the market at all times.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to remove `strategy.position_size == 0` from your entry conditions as it doesn't make too much sense.

By default, the strategies are executed when a bar is closed so you can also remove this `barstate.isconfirmed` condition.

And also `not na(maFast) and not na(maSlow)` conditions because if they are `na`, there won't be a "cross" anyway.

Additionally, you should change your short exit condition as it checks if the position is long at the moment. Please note that, your `strategy.close` functions will not be called because you will be switching direction with the same condition.

```
if strategy.position_size < 0 and bullCross
    strategy.close(id="short")
```